# "IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array" error in processing when using append();

Tags: class, arraylist, processing

My code is as so...

```
ArrayList<Ray> rays = new ArrayList<Ray>();

Particle() {
  for(int a=0; a < 360; a+=10) {
    append(rays, new Ray(position, radians(a)));
  }
}
```

I'm initializing an ArrayList of the class Ray. Then I run through a for loop and am attempting to
append a new Ray() to the list. I get no errors in the editor but whenever I run the code I get the error message: `IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array`

I've looked around and nothing seems to answer my question. Why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry about that! I don't use Stack Overflow that often so I wasn't aware you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`append`](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html) function is for use with arrays (e.g.: `rays[]`). However `rays` is an [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html). Hence, you need to use the `add` method:

<s>`append(rays, new Ray(position, radians(a)));`</s>

```java
rays.add(new Ray(position, radians(a));
```